# iPhone NSUser Defaults

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I HAVE STORED NSString value in NSUserDefaults, however didn't know how to retrieve that stored value into another string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting value

```
NSString* pin = @"somthig";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:pin forKey:@"TokenPin"];
```

getting value

```
NSString* pin;
pin = (NSString*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"TokenPin"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Kashif have a look on **[this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)** tutorial and have look at the data retrieving part....like this

```
Retrieving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float
float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for accessing

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        yourString= [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as like below,

```
NSString *retrieveString =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"key"];
```